# Covert int to int array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, int

So I am pretty new to programming. I am taking an intro to java class and I am trying to submit my project, however, I am getting the error "int cannot be converted to int[]". The program compiles fine and it works but when it submits to to my web-cat. It cannot reference it.

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Guess the 3 digit code and this program will tell you how many
 * digits you have right and once you guess the correct code,
 * it'll tell you how many guesses it took you.
 * Press 0 to exit the program.
 *
 * @author (philtsoi)
 * @version (10/05/2017)
 */
public class CodeCracker {
    /**
     *  calls the play method
     *  
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        play();
    }
    /**
     * starts the game
     */
    public static void play() {
        System.out.println("Guess my 3-digit code?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random random = new Random();
        int correctd = random.nextInt(900) + 100; // random 3-digit code

        int[] code = new int[3]; // array that holds 3 integers
        int extract = 0; // extract is the one digit of guess
        int input = 0; // input is the digits the player types in
        int counter = 0; // counter is the number of guesses
        int correct = counter; // correct is the digits correct 

        extract = correctd / 100;
        code[0] = extract; // first digit
        correctd = correctd - extract * 100;
        extract = correctd / 10;
        code[1] = extract; // second digit
        correctd = correctd - extract * 10;
        code[2] = correctd; // third digit

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Your guess? ");
            input = in .nextInt();
            counter++;
            if (input == 0) {
                System.out.println("Ok.Maybe another time.");
                break;
            } else {
                correct = checkGuess(code, input);
                System.out.println(input + " - " + correct + " digits correct");
                if (correct == 3) {
                    System.out.println("You got it in " + counter + " times");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method checkGuess goes through the code and calculates each 
     * digit and returns the number of correct ones
     * 
     * @param code[] the array that the number being guesses is stored in
     * @param guess the integer of the next guessed digit
     * @return number of correct digits
     */
    public static int checkGuess(int code[], int guess) {
        int count = 0; // count is the number of digits correct
        int extract = guess / 100; // extract is the one digit of guess
        if (code[0] == extract) {
            count++;
            guess -= extract * 100;
            extract = guess / 10;
        }
        if (code[1] == extract) {
            count++;
            guess -= extract * 10;
        }
        if (code[2] == guess) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

I know for a fact that the problem that is wrong is the checkGuess method. Any help would be appreciated.

These are the errors I am getting:

**Errors**
[image: Errors]

Comment: where does your error occured

Comment: Which line causes the error? What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: The tests pass in the code as a single three-digit integer; you have to move the `code[0] = extract`, etc to within the function.

Comment: The test cases expect the `checkGuess` method to have the following signature: `int checkGuess(int, int)`. You are specifying the first argument to be an int array. You need to conform it to the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

this method `checkGuess(int code[], int guess)` is expecting an array followed by an int as parameter, you just can not call it passing 2 ints..

the class testing the code is the one failing, you defined the variable code as an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use the array. So, just comment out what you do not use, and just use the number, **correctd**!

```
//      int[] code = new int[3]; // array that holds 3 integers
//      int extract = 0; // extract is the one digit of guess
        int input = 0; // input is the digits the player types in
        int counter = 0; // counter is the number of guesses
        int correct = counter; // correct is the digits correct

//      extract = correctd / 100;
//      code[0] = extract; // first digit
//      correctd = correctd - extract * 100;
//      extract = correctd / 10;
//      code[1] = extract; // second digit
//      correctd = correctd - extract * 10;
//      code[2] = correctd; // third digit
```

If you just use the number, instead of array, it should be done like this.

```
public static int checkGuess(int code, int guess) {
    int count = 0; // count is the number of digits correct
    while(code != 0 && guess != 0){
        if(code % 10 == guess % 10){
            count++;
        }
        code /= 10;
        guess /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also, don't forget to call the method, with correctd, not the array.

```
...
        } else {
            correct = checkGuess(correctd, input);
            System.out.println(input + " - " + correct + " digits correct");
...
```